# TypeError deleting a file with gridfs mongoose and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an application that allows uploading and downloading music.
I can upload files, send them to the client... however, I have problems when it comes to deleting a bucket file...

I'am using "mongoose": "^6.2.1".

My controller, where podcastId is a ObjectId:

```
const connection = require('../database')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Users = require('../models/Users')
const PodcastInfo = require('../models/PodcastInfo')

ctrPod.deletePodcast = async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
    
        const id = req.params.idPodInfo
        const info = await PodcastInfo.findById(id)
        const { userId, podcastId } = info
        const gridFsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(connection, {
        bucketName: 'podcasts',
        });

        gridFsBucket.delete(podcastId, (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
.
.
.
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'client' in undefined
    at getTopology
```

The problem appears here, \node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:363:23) :

```
function getTopology(provider) {
    if (`topology` in provider && provider.topology) {
        return provider.topology;
    }
    else if ('client' in provider.s && provider.s.client.topology) {
        return provider.s.client.topology;
    }
    else if ('db' in provider.s && provider.s.db.s.client.topology) {
        return provider.s.db.s.client.topology;
    }
    throw new error_1.MongoNotConnectedError('MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation');
}
////////////////////////
 delete(id, callback) {
        return (0, utils_1.executeLegacyOperation)((0, utils_1.getTopology)(this.s.db), _delete, [this, id, callback], {
            skipSessions: true
        });
    }
/////////////////////////////////////
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here:

```
 const gridFsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(connection, {
        bucketName: 'podcasts',
        });
```

`new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(db,{bucketName})` takes in a `db` not a `connection`. Try:

```
const gridFsBucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(connection.db, {
        bucketName: 'podcasts',
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I create the mongoose instance like this: `const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOSE_URL_CLOUD,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    
})

const connection = mongoose.connection

connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log('DB is conected')
})

module.exports = connection`  I may have to use createConnection().